# Google Analytics Embed API date issue

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I am using Google Analytics embed javascript API to display analytics chart. 
When it brings the data, it only brings only one day in last month.

[image]

Please look into the highlighted date. End date I used is Jan 11. But result came only upto Jan 2.
Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to stack please supply us with a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  we can not tell you why your code isn't working if we cant test it.

Comment: As @DaImTo said you should include your full request and the raw response. It could be your application has [`include-empty-rows`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#includeEmptyRows) set to **False**,or that the [max-results](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#maxResults) set to 31. Try your query in the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) and include that in your question.

Comment: Thank you. include empty rows helped me.